# Storing hexagonal shape grid data into an array

Tags: javascript, html, grid, hexagonal-tiles

I'm generating hexagonal shape grid as explained in Amit Patel's website [redblobgames.com](http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/implementation.html#map)

I have tested the grid and everything , including the coordinates is correct.

Now I'd like to store the grid data into an array. I partially figured it out, however the main problem is that some columns start at index **1** instead of **0**.

So I'd like to find a way how to place the hexes in same order but make all  starting from **0**.

The index has to be calculated off the [q,r, -q-r] square positions, so that I can then access the array using the same technique.

this is how I'm now generating the grid and storing the data:

```
for (var q = -this.grid_r; q <= this.grid_r; q++) {
        var r1 = Math.max(-this.grid_r, -q - this.grid_r);
        var r2 = Math.min(this.grid_r, -q + this.grid_r);
        for (var r = r1; r <= r2; r++) {
            row = r + this.grid_r ;
            col = (q+Math.floor(r/2)) + this.grid_r;
            if( ! this.hexes[ row ] ){
                this.hexes[ row ] = [];
            }
            n_hex = new Hex( q, r, this.layout );
            this.hexes[ row ][ col ] = n_hex;
        }
    }
```

This is how the array look like from the data perspective.

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6
0       0   0   0   0   
1       0   0   0   0   0 
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   
3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   0   0   0   
5       0   0   0   0   0   
6       0   0   0   0
```

I just want to avoid using any conditions in draw or update methods to check whether the column is empty or not.

```
draw: function( ctx ){
        for( var r = 0, r_l = this.hexes.length; r < r_l;  r++ ){
            for( var c = 0, c_l = this.hexes.length; c < c_l;  c++ ){
               if( typeof( this.hexes[r][c]) !== "undefined" ){ 
                   this.hexes[r][c].draw( ctx );
               }
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your outer loop is `q` and your inner loop is `r`. Your array indices need to follow the same structure, with `this.hexes[col][row]` instead of `this.hexes[row][col]`:

```
for (var q = -this.grid_r; q <= this.grid_r; q++) {
    var r1 = Math.max(-this.grid_r, -q - this.grid_r);
    var r2 = Math.min(this.grid_r, -q + this.grid_r);
    for (var r = r1; r <= r2; r++) {
        col = q + this.grid_r;
        row = r - r1;
        if (!this.hexes[col]) { this.hexes[col] = []; }
        this.hexes[col][row] = new Hex(q, r, this.layout);
    }
}
```

The `col` will be `q` minus where the `q` loop starts (`-this.grid_r`). The `row` will be `r` minus where the `r` loop starts (`r1`).